# Inserting Null value in table after click on update command in codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter

I am updating the record but its inserting only Null value in database, Its not taking the value which i am inserting form from.Please check the below code.I am a new in codeigniter.Please help me in this.

**Controller**

```
public function update1()
    {
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$this->load->model("model_add_user");

$data['posts'] = $this->model_add_user->update1($id);
$data['user'] = $this->model_add_user->select();


$this->load->view('index',$data);

}
```

**Model**

```
public function update1($userId)
{


  $data = array(



'date'=>$this->input->post('date'),

'firtsname'=>$this->input->post('firtsname'),

 'middlename'=>$this->input->post('middlename'),

'lastname'=>$this->input->post('lastname'),

 'mobileno'=>$this->input->post('mobileno'),
 'landline'=>$this->input->post('landline'),

 'address'=>$this->input->post('address'),
 'city'=>$this->input->post('city'),

 'locality'=>$this->input->post('locality'),
 'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),

            );

$this->db->where('userId',$userId);
$this->db->update('add_user',$data);


}
```

**view**

```
<?php  
         foreach ($posts as $post)  
         {  
            ?>
    <input type="text" name="userId" placeholder="USER ID" style="width:500px" value='<?php echo $post->userId;?>'>&nbsp;


    <input type="date" name="date" style="width:500px" value='<?php echo $post->date;?>'>
    <input type="text" name="firtsname" placeholder="FIRST NAME" style="width:330px" value='<?php echo $post->firtsname;?>'>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="middlename" placeholder="MIDDLE NAME" style="width:330px" value='<?php echo $post->middlename;?>'>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="LAST NAME" style="width:330px" value='<?php echo $post->lastname;?>'>&nbsp;

    <input type="text" name="mobileno" placeholder="ENTER MOBILE NO." style="width:500px" value='<?php echo $post->mobileno;?>'>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="landline" placeholder="LANDLINE No." style="width:500px" value='<?php echo $post->landline;?>'>
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="ENTER ADDRESS" ><?php echo $post->address;?></textarea>

    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="CITY" style="width:500px" value='<?php echo $post->city;?>'>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="locality" placeholder="LOCALITY" style="width:500px" value='<?php echo $post->locality;?>'>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="ENTER EMAIL" style="width:1010px" value='<?php echo $post->email;?>'></br>

  <a href="<?php echo site_url('Welcome/update1/'.$post->userId)?>"><input type="submit" class="submit" name="UPDATE" value="UPDATE" ></a>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url('')?>" role="button" ><input type="submit" class="submit" name="UPDATE" value="Cancel" ></a>
   <?php }  

         ?>
```

Comment: can you post `$posts` array contain?? use `print_r($posts)`

Comment: according to your code, Its not taking the null value but update command is not working.I am getting same value which already in database

Comment: Mr.Abdulla where i have to use your code

Comment: in controller before load view and next line use `die();`

Comment: i am getting blank page output

Comment: remove `die()` and try once

Comment: i think you place that in wrong place or data not receiving for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi bro here what i can offer:
View:

```
   <?php 
         foreach ($posts as $post) 
         { 
            ?>
  <?php echo form_Open('welcome/update_process');?>
    <input type="text" name="userId" placeholder="USER ID" style="width:50px" value='<?php echo $post->userId;?>'>&nbsp;


    <input type="date" name="date" style="width:500px" value='<?php echo $post->date;?>'>
    <input type="text" name="firtsname" placeholder="FIRST NAME" style="width:330px" value='<?php echo $post->firtsname;?>'>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="middlename" placeholder="MIDDLE NAME" style="width:330px" value='<?php echo $post->middlename;?>'>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="LAST NAME" style="width:330px" value='<?php echo $post->lastname;?>'>&nbsp;

    <input type="text" name="mobileno" placeholder="ENTER MOBILE NO." style="width:500px" value='<?php echo $post->mobileno;?>'>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="landline" placeholder="LANDLINE No." style="width:500px" value='<?php echo $post->landline;?>'>
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="ENTER ADDRESS" ><?php echo $post->address;?></textarea>

    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="CITY" style="width:500px" value='<?php echo $post->city;?>'>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="locality" placeholder="LOCALITY" style="width:500px" value='<?php echo $post->locality;?>'>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="ENTER EMAIL" style="width:1010px" value='<?php echo $post->email;?>'></br>

  <input type="submit" class="submit" name="UPDATE" value="UPDATE" >
  <a href="<?php echo base_url('')?>" role="button" class="submit">Cancel</a>
  <?php echo form_close();?>
   <?php } 

         ?> 
<?php endif ?>
```

Controller:

```
    public function update_process()
{
    $this->load->model("model_add_user");

    $id = $this->input->post('userId');

    $data = array(
    'date'=>$this->input->post('date'),

    'firtsname'=>$this->input->post('firtsname'),

     'middlename'=>$this->input->post('middlename'),

    'lastname'=>$this->input->post('lastname'),

     'mobileno'=>$this->input->post('mobileno'),
     'landline'=>$this->input->post('landline'),

     'address'=>$this->input->post('address'),
     'city'=>$this->input->post('city'),

     'locality'=>$this->input->post('locality'),
     'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),

            );
    $result = $this->model_add_user->update_data($id,$data);
    if ($result == "true") {
        redirect('welcome/update_retrive/'.$id);
    } else {
        echo "cannot update";
    }


}
```

Model:

```
   function update_data($id,$data)
{
  $query = $this->db->where('userId',$id)
           ->update('add_user',$data);

           if ($query) {
             return "true";
           } else {
             return "false";
           }

}
```

Comment: sorry bro this code it not working.Its not talking any action when i clicked on update buton